Negative drag coefficient of the main airfoil in a multi-element configuration in CFD SU2
I get this strange result where the Cd on the mainplane of a Rear Wing of F1 is negative. However the Cd of the entire configuration (mainplane+flap) remains positive. Is there any possible physical explanation? Or there's something that must be changed in the set up of the CFD. I'm using SU2.
In this link I uploaded all the settings. The .su2 file is the mesh input file. In the config file there's the setup of the simulation however Mach=~0.2, standard TD conditions, RANS with SST turbulence model the other numerical settings are taken from a similar case. I included also the output files, in the history.csv there are the aerodynamic coefficients and the residuals and all the other stuff while in force_breakdown.dat there's written how to retrieve forces because su2, in this case, performs a non-dimensional computation.
I also extrapolated from Paraview and included the Cp.csv file, It contains surface data of the whole Rear Wing. In each column: Point ID, x-coord.,y-coord.,z-coord.,pressure, pressure_coefficient and y_plus. The Cp distribution along the multi-element wing seems to be okay.

Phenomena don't just exist alone. Try just the main airfoil. If that result makes sense, your simulation is probably working. What does that tell you about the forces required to hold the two airfoils together?
